# My question is still closed after editing

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518318/how-to-correctly-write-code-without-iframe-for-displaying-facebook-page-on-the) was closed with a message.

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.

Yes, it was my fault that I did not write the question enough. However, even after editing, it is still closed.

I'm sorry, but I didn't understand the documentation. When will the question reopen, please?

Comment: Which one? Link?

Comment: If you are talking about [render FB page on my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518318/how-to-correctly-write-code-without-iframe-for-displaying-facebook-page-on-the) question than keep in mind that an attempt to build a phishing site  may easily attract downvotes/close votes even if strictly speaking it is not against CoC.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This does not look remotely malicious to me, OP's trying to do something that FB explicitly provides a plugin for.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ? Plugin adds IFrame to protect content of FB page (which is what any non-malicious site should expect) - OP clearly spelled out that their don't want that  "but without using an iframe, which causes a error" and explicitly said they want to access content inside the page. I'm not saying that OP have malicious intent by themselves ("Never Attribute to Malice That Which Is Adequately Explained by Stupidity") but for some people that could look like really malicious intent (at least CoC essentially says we should assume OP knows what they asking for)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, yes this is a question.  Anyway, this is the company's website, where I want to display his Facebook page, but for security reasons, I did not list them.  Like the code that was generated from another Facebook page.  So how should I write it, please?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming it's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518318/how-to-correctly-write-code-without-iframe-for-displaying-facebook-page-on-the). It currently has 2 of the 3 reopen votes it needs to be reopened.

Unfortunately for you when it went through the reopen queue it also attracted 3 leave closed votes. That means overall that queue determined the question should stay closed.

The 2 reopen votes remain however and should someone else come across it with the power and determination to reopen it then they can currently singlehandedly reopen it by adding that missing third reopen vote.

Is there anything else you think you could do to improve the question so it gets that last reopen vote? Posting code as images isn't something we want here so you could fix that.

Comment: This is what I find hostile with Stack Overflow. After edit, the question is still burdened with downvotes - these should be cleared. The edit might be a very large edit, replacing the old question, and still it is closed and downvoted. Since no one gets to see the question, no one is able to upvote and thus accounts get stuck in the freezer forever.

Comment: Can we have the time back that we spent reading the old question then? What you have is encouragement to polish it before posting rather than afterwards.

Answer (score -3):

## Short answer

Editing a question does not mean it reopens immediately.

## Long answer

If, for example, you edit a question which is closed, then if one <strike>determined</strike> user stumbles into the question and clicks "reopen", it goes into the reopen queue. You need 3 reopen votes to be reopened.

And see @Robert Longson's answer for information on how to improve the question.

Comment: *"if one user stumbles into the question and clicks "reopen", it goes into the reopen queue."*, this is only half right, the first edit after closure also pushes questions into the queue, otherwise closed questions wouldn't really have a chance